# Bluetooth headphone sound getting choppy and laggy when i don't use any audio source for a while at Windows 7(PC)

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I bought a new bluetooth headphone Plantatronics Backbeat fit 305. It works fine with phones but when it comes to pc it's not that good. If i connected it recently it sounds well but sound become intermittent and laggy when i don't use any audio at pc for a while(about 45 seconds). I need to reconnect the headphone to fix it.

I need help to fix this. And thanks everyone...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the drivers you have installed for this device are the latest version and are official drivers from the manufacturer, if not then I'd suggest removing the old drivers and installing the newest ones.
If this does not resolve the issue, next time the sound becomes laggy check that your cpu/memory usage is not unusually high, and if so does that change when you disconnect the headphones?

Comment: Hi, thanks your answer. I checked CPU/Memory usage and it was normal. And windows says driver is the latest update.  I dont know if theres a driver for my headphones. Thanks again....

Comment: From a look on the plantronics website this might help you with the issue, might be worth trying https://www.plantronics.com/gb/en/support/downloads-apps/hub-desktop

Comment: I think that software doesnt support my model :( Ty anyway